# Why does this CSS code not work correctly with Chrome, but works with Mozilla?

Tags: html, css

This code which is working perfect with Mozilla but has a small issue in Chrome.

#### Chrome result:

[image: screenshot]

#### Mozilla result:

[image: screeshot]

The code:

```css
h3.title-text {
  background: #fafafa none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: -15px 0 15px -30px;
  padding: 3px 50px 15px 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
}
h3.title-text edger::before {
  border-bottom: 36px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 7px;
}
h3.title-text edger::after {
  border-bottom: 41px solid #000;
  border-right: 27px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
}
h3.title-text edger {
  background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
  outline: 0 none;
  padding: 10px 19px 10px 32px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  top: 4px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="title-text"><edger>
<i class="fa fa-apple"></i>
      Latest Softwares</edger></h3>
```

So why the edge show quite bigger in chrome browser ? while it seems ok in mozilla. please look into the code which property is used wrong or not supported in chrome. thanks.

Comment: The edge is not the problem. The "edger" has 1 less pixel height in chrome (20 instead of 21 in firefox). I don't know why it happens, probably a rounding difference in the calculation of "auto" height. You can fix it by applying display:inline-block, and manually setting the height to the edger element.

Comment: @pkExec exactly but could you give me a jsfiddle example...if you can resolve this issue..i almost spend 3 hours but cannot do that

Comment: The difference is in how firefox and chrome calculate the height of fonts.  SInce your edger class is inline and not a block type, it uses the height of the text (plus padding) to determine it's size, which is 40px in chrome, while the edger:after is 41px.  The easy solution is to add `display: inline-block` to the edger class and set the height.

Comment: @RobertMcKee thanks buddy can you please spend about 1 minute to share your code in jsfiddle or here. i try but i think i did somewhere mistake..so kindly please share the code you make changes..thanks

Comment: @SkyRocket Do you use 2 accounts here? .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142604/different-effect-happened-mozilla-and-chrome-show-different-result-why ... or you go to the same school??

Comment: @LGSon no i don't use 2 account. I asked the same question in my facebook programming group. it seems someone other want to resolve the issue for me with stackoverflow...i am using only this account. i got help each time i posted my issue..thanks bundles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @pkExec comment, here is updated code snippet:

```css
h3.title-text {
  background: #fafafa none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: -15px 0 15px -30px;
  padding: 3px 50px 15px 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
}
h3.title-text edger::before {
  border-bottom: 36px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 7px;
}
h3.title-text edger::after {
  border-bottom: 41px solid #000;
  border-right: 27px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
}
h3.title-text edger {
  background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
  outline: 0 none;
  padding: 10px 19px 10px 32px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  top: 4px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="title-text"><edger>
<i class="fa fa-apple"></i>
      Latest Softwares</edger></h3>
```

Or on the edger rule you can omit the 'height: 21px;' and change the padding to: 12px 19px 11px 32px;

Comment: @plubsauced1 thanks for sharing the code...appreciated your work..thanks again it worked

Answer (score 0):

I know how frustrating that sort of thing can be. Cross-browser incompatibilities are a real pain!

What I would recommend, and what I have been doing lately, is including code at the beginning of my CSS stylesheets that will reset whatever browser my site is being viewed in, so I can code from the perspective of a "level" playing field. I have found it to really help eliminate issues like what you're having. Here is the code I like to use...

```
/* ========== Browser Reset ========== */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Give that a spin and see if it helps.

Comment: actually it doesn't do any changes. I just tested your suggestion.

Comment: @shenole i would not work....i tried a lot other tricks..i dont know why it is happening ? please refer someone  if some body can do this for me...jsfiddle example will be appreciated.

Comment: Sky Rocket... sorry I didn't get back right away. I just forwarded the issue to a friend of mine who is more experienced than me. Maybe he can figure it out. In the meantime I will try to figure something out too. After all, we are all here to learn!

Comment: Hey Sky Rocket... I'm stumped! I've been on it for a day now. Is the website up where I could go and look at it and use Chrome's Developer Tools to take a closer look at things?